# Oracle CASE missing right parenthesis for a "in" limit

Tags: sql, oracle, spotfire

I have a QRY im developing in Oracle for spotfire. In the where statement, I have a decision case statement and if its True, im trying to pass a list of items to match a column,  below is what I have, but its throwing a missing right parenthesis error and I cannot determine why. In short, when a variable is determined True (in this case 9>8 for the example, I need it to result those items,  else, result the entire column with no limits.
Note: This works fine when its only 1 item being passed, i.e. 'BOB'  but as soon as its multiple, this error occurs.

```
and  Column1 = (CASE When 9>8 Then ('BOB','TOM') Else Column1 END)
```

Comment: A case expression's different return values must have matching data types, and ('BOB','TOM') and column1 have different types.

Comment: Also, a `Column1 = ('BOB','TOM')` comparison is not valid.

Comment: A case expression returns a single, atomic value. `('BOB','TOM')` are two values.

Answer (score 1):

Case expressions are best avoided in the where clause. Instead, write the logic with `AND` and `OR`:

```
And (
        (9>8 AND Column1 IN ('BOB','TOM')) 
        OR 9<=8 -- You say you check a variable here, don't forget to check for NULL
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not have a boolean type for use in SQL queries.

Instead, just use basic logic:

```
and  ( (9 > 8 and Column1 in ('BOB','TOM')) or
       9 <= 8
     )
```